# SetItemCheckState breaks foreach! Help?

Tags: c#, foreach, checkedlistbox

I'm new here and have a question about C#'s CheckedListBox.

I built the CheckedListBox with data from a SQLite Database file.

I want the user to check or uncheck items and in doing so it updates in the database.

When you open the list again the Items you previously checked should still be checked. Ie if the boolean field in the database says "true" for a specific item, it should be checked.

Heres the code I'm using:

```
index = 0;
        foreach (DataRowView item in CheckedListBox.Items)
            {
                if (item.Row["viewed"].ToString() == "true")
                {                        
                   CheckedListBox.SetItemCheckState(index, CheckState.Checked);                        
                }
                index++;
            }
```

When I comment out the line in the If statement the loop goes through all the items, but when i leave it like it is above, the loop only enters once.

Why is that?

I'm really new to C#.

Thank you for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `for loop` instead of `foreach`.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (((DataRowView)checkedListBox1.Items[i]).Row["viewed"].ToString() == "true")
            {
                checkedListBox1.SetItemCheckState(i, CheckState.Checked);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) How do I check a specific item's value when in a for loop as opposed to `item.Row["viewed"].ToString() == "true"` in the foreach? And I'm not really sure if that would solve the problem anyway. What is your reasoning?

Comment: Wow! That works!! Thanks so much! :D I don't understand why though? Why does this work but the foreach does not?

Comment: You are changing the Items of checkedListBox during enumeration. foreach is depend on enumeration that may be the reason here.